# Как получить значение input type="range"

Tags: javascript, html, input, range

Есть у меня `<input>`:

```
<form action="">
    <input type="range" value="25" max="100" min="0">
</form>
```

У которого я двигаю бегунок. Как мне  получить значение, текущего положения бегунка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("myrange").addEventListener("change", function() {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<input id="myrange" type="range" value="25" max="100" min="0">
```

Comment: Спасибо!! очень помогли

Comment: @TigranVardanyan На здоровье. Успехов!

Answer (score 4):

Если использовать jQuery:

```js
$('.result').html($('input[type="range"]').val());

$(document).on('input change', 'input[type="range"]', function() {
  $('.result').html($(this).val());
});
```

```css
.result {
  height: 30px;
  border:1px solid;
  margin: 2rem 0;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<form action="">
    <input type="range" value="25" max="100" min="0">
</form>
  
  <div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: и вам спасибо!!

Comment: @HamSter Поздравляю с новым достижением в репутации - 15к!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, Спасибо!))